# stored procedure for inserting comma seperated values in table using ms sql?

Tags: sql-server-2008, java-stored-procedures

I have a table named assignRole.

I am passing string of userid (int) csv ,and passing roleid(int).

I want a stored procedure which split userid from string and take roleid and insert these values in table.this thing is to happen for all values in userid string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitInts]
(
   @List       VARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN ( SELECT Item = CONVERT(INT, Item) FROM ( 
     SELECT Item = x.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'int') FROM ( 
       SELECT [XML] = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') 
       + '</i>').query('.') ) AS a CROSS APPLY [XML].nodes('i') AS x(i)) AS y
     WHERE Item IS NOT NULL
   );
```

Now you can say:

```
INSERT dbo.assignRole(RoleID, UserID)
  SELECT @RoleID, Item
  FROM dbo.SplitInts(@UserIDList, ',');
```

Comment: @user1506955 no problem. Please search next time, this is probably one of the most frequently asked SQL Server questions.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use a table-valued function to do the split.

IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.StrSplit') IS NOT NULL DROP FUNCTION dbo.[StrSplit]
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[StrSplit]
(
       @String VARCHAR(MAX), @Delimiter char(1)
)
RETURNS 
       @Results TABLE (
              Items NVARCHAR(MAX)
       )
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @INDEX INT
    DECLARE @SLICE nvarchar(MAX)

```
-- HAVE TO SET TO 1 SO IT DOESNT EQUAL ZERO FIRST TIME IN LOOP
SELECT @INDEX = 1


-- Early exit if passed string is null
IF @String IS NULL RETURN

WHILE @INDEX !=0
BEGIN 
          -- GET THE INDEX OF THE FIRST OCCURENCE OF THE SPLIT CHARACTER
          SELECT @INDEX = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@STRING)

          -- NOW PUSH EVERYTHING TO THE LEFT OF IT INTO THE SLICE VARIABLE
          IF @INDEX !=0
                 SELECT @SLICE = LEFT(@STRING,@INDEX - 1)
          ELSE
                 SELECT @SLICE = @STRING
          -- PUT THE ITEM INTO THE RESULTS SET
          INSERT INTO @Results(Items) VALUES(@SLICE)
          -- CHOP THE ITEM REMOVED OFF THE MAIN STRING
          SELECT @STRING = RIGHT(@STRING,LEN(@STRING) - @INDEX)
          -- BREAK OUT IF WE ARE DONE
          IF LEN(@STRING) = 0 BREAK
END
RETURN
```

END

GO
GRANT SELECT ON [dbo].[StrSplit] TO [public]